# drawing complex tree with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

Please how can I draw this tree with TikZ please?

[image]

My problem is how to join two children and create a new node with labels?

The current code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,11pt,oneside]{book} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right] 
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle]; 
    \node{r} 
        child { node {a} 
            child { node {c} }
            child { node {d} }
            child { node {e} } 
        } 
        child [missing] 
        child [missing] 
        child { node {b} 
            child { node {c} } 
            child { node {d} } 
            child { node {e} } 
         }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot my problem is how to join different nodes to a square?

Comment: Please add the code you've got so we can understand which nodes you want to join to which square. Right now, i have no idea what the problem is or how you are drawing the tree. Also, I'm not sure it *is* a tree since some children have multiple parents.

Comment: Hello, thanls a lot for your help, this is l'example. in need to finish drawing the tree, i do until this : \documentclass[a4paper,openany,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right]

\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle];
\node{r}
    child { node {a} 
        child { node {c} }
        child { node {d} }
        child { node {e} }
    }
    child [missing]
    child [missing]
    child {node {b} 
        child { node {c} }
        child { node {d} }
        child { node {e} }
    };

\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: I added your code to the question, corrected and formatted it. So far this things works fine, you probably need to be more precise about your actual problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can give a name to the tree, by giving a name to its root node, and then each node of the tree receives also an automatically generated name of the form `(root-n-m)`, being `root` the name given to the root node, and `n` the ordinal of the first-level children, and `m` the ordinal of the second-level child. This name defines a "path" through the tree to any desired node.

Using those names you can add tikz commands to draw lines to other nodes, external to the tree.

For example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{trees, positioning} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right] 
    \tikzset{
      every node/.style = {draw,shape=circle},
      every label/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw=none}
      }
    \node (t) {r} 
        child { node {a} 
            child { node {c} }
            child { node {d} }
            child { node {e} } 
            child { node {f} } 
        } 
        child [missing] 
        child [missing] 
        child { node {b} 
            child { node {c} } 
            child { node {d} } 
            child { node {e} } 
         }; 

    \node[rectangle, draw, below right=5mm and 3cm of t-4-3, label={$p=0.3$}]  (S1) {S11, s22};
    \node[rectangle, draw, below=1.8cm of S1 , label={$p=0.5$}]  (S2) {S11, s24};
    \node[rectangle, draw, below=of S2,        label={$p=0.12$}] (S3) {S12, s23};
    \node[rectangle, draw, below=1.8cm of S3,  label={$p=0.6$}]  (S4) {S13, s22};

    \foreach \start/\finish in {t-4-3/S1,t-4-3/S2,t-4-2/S3,t-4-1/S4,t-1-4/S1,t-1-3/S4,t-1-2/S3,t-1-1/S2}
       \draw[blue, ->] (\start) -- (\finish.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Since this is not a tree, and since for an optimal result the nodes have to be positioned visually, I suggest to draw the nodes and edges explicitly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{nblue}{blue!50}
\colorlet{nred}{brown!50!red}
\colorlet{norange}{orange!50}
\colorlet{ngreen}{green!50}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\tikzset
  {common/.style={blue,draw,fill=#1,text=white},
   single/.style={common=#1,ellipse,inner sep=1pt},
   multiple/.style 2 args=
    {common=#1,rounded corners,label=above:{\scriptsize$P=#2$},
     minimum width=4em,inner sep=2pt
    }
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[single=nblue,inner sep=3pt]                              (s)       {$s$};
  \node[single=nblue,above right=of s,yshift=5mm]                (s1)      {$s_1$};
  \node[single=nblue,below right=of s,yshift=-5mm]               (s2)      {$s_2$};
  \node[single=nred,above right=of s1,yshift=-5mm]               (s11)     {$s_{11}$};
  \node[single=ngreen,right=of s1]                               (s12)     {$s_{12}$};
  \node[single=norange,below right=of s1,yshift=5mm]             (s13)     {$s_{13}$};
  \node[single=nred,above right=of s2]                           (s21)     {$s_{21}$};
  \node[single=norange,right=of s2,yshift=5mm]                   (s22)     {$s_{22}$};
  \node[single=ngreen,right=of s2,yshift=-5mm]                   (s23)     {$s_{23}$};
  \node[single=nred,below right=of s2]                           (s24)     {$s_{24}$};
  \node[multiple={nred}{0.2},right=of s12,xshift=1cm,yshift=2mm] (s11s22)  {$s_{11},s_{22}$};
  \node[multiple={nred}{0.5},below=of s11s22]                    (s11s24)  {$s_{11},s_{24}$};
  \node[multiple={ngreen}{0.12},below=of s11s24]                 (s12s23)  {$s_{12},s_{23}$};
  \node[multiple={norange}{0.6},below=of s12s23]                 (s13s22)  {$s_{13},s_{22}$};
  \node[multiple={ngreen}{0.12},right=of s11s22,yshift=-7mm]     (s12s23b) {$s_{12},s_{23}$};
  \node[multiple={nred}{0.3},below=of s12s23b]                   (s11s22b) {$s_{11},s_{22}$};
  \node[multiple={norange}{0.6},below=of s11s22b]                (s13s22b) {$s_{13},s_{22}$};
  \foreach \f/\t in
    {s/s1,s/s2,s1/s11,s1/s12,s1/s13,s2/s21,s2/s22,s2/s23,s2/s24,%
     s11/s11s22,s11/s11s24,s12/s12s23,s13/s13s22,s21/s11s22,s22/s13s22,%
     s22/s13s22,s23/s12s23,s24/s11s24,s11s22/s11s22b,s12s23/s12s23b,s13s22/s13s22b%
    }
    \draw[blue,-latex] (\f.east) -- (\t.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how to modify all sij by $s_{ij}$ and si by $s_i$

Comment: With the search/replace function of your editor?